# iOS PDF editing - Combining FastPDFKit / CGPDFContext and libHaru

Tags: ios, pdf, cgpdfcontext, libharu

I'm trying to add PDF Annotations onto an existing PDF file in iOS.

I understand that using FASTPDFKit / CGPDFContext, it is possible to READ ( but not EDIT ) almost all the information from an existing PDF File ( Correct me if I'm wrong ).

I also understand that using libHaru, it is a piece of cake to create annotations on a new PDF file. But libHaru does not support reading of existing PDF's.

Is there any constraint combining these 2 libraries so that I can add annotations onto an existing PDF file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to me, i think we can add custom annotation using fastpdfkit...look it in fastpdfkit feature manual i.e http://mobfarm.eu/features

Answer (score 0):

Considering that libHaru does not support reading of existing PDF files, I cannot see how you could achieve what you want. Of course you can use all of those libraries together, but you will still have to work with separate PDF documents and you won't be able to add annotations to your existing PDF.

I don't know much about FASTPDFKit, but I can tell you that with CGPDFContext you can't just modify the stream or add new stuff to an existing stream.